# remove non-printing characters

Tags: grep, sed, awk

I have a tab delimited text file. When I open the file with vi editor, I can see ^M character (in blue color). This is not part of my data.
It got there because the original SQL data had carriage return /r sign.

```
713498  29195   NWSO    NE SA COLLEGE  2       O-      0.3     0.3     0.0     1               MHR     N       Y       Y       ^M      aher
```

How do I remove this character without affeting the tab locations? 
In other words there should be 2 tabs between the last Y and "aher" word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `vi` you can replace all `^M` characters with command mode

`:%s/`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>`//g`

This will remove all those `^M`

**OR**

You can do it with `sed` also:

`sed -i 's/`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>`//g'  filename`

Comment: For versions of `sed` such as GNU `sed` which support it, you can use the escape representation of a carriage return: `sed -i 's/\r//g'`. The same is true of `vi`.

Answer (score 4):

Translate has shown it's power!

```
tr -d "\r"
```